# SQLAlchemy Biquery Connection is insanely slow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

I've been setting up a datastructure in BigQuery and wanted to interacted with it through SQLAlchemy as an ORM.

The issue is, it's insanely slow. Uploading 20ish rows of data took me 90 seconds.
I compared it with using the BigQuery client library and it worked very fast, so I suspect the SQLAlchemy library / the BigQuery dialect is causing the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Any help is much appreciated.
Code snippet below:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import time

engine = create_engine('bigquery://xxx',
                   credentials_path="yyy.json", echo=True, arraysize=1000, use_query_cache=True)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Region'
    RegionID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Name = Column(String)
    
data = [{'Name':'Bayern', 'RegionID' : 0},
{'Name':'Südwest', 'RegionID' : 1},
{'Name':'Hessen', 'RegionID' : 2},
{'Name':'Niedersachsen', 'RegionID' : 3},
{'Name':'Sachsen-Anhalt', 'RegionID' : 4},
{'Name':'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern', 'RegionID' : 5},
{'Name':'Westfalen', 'RegionID' : 6},
{'Name':'Württemberg', 'RegionID' : 7},
{'Name':'Sachsen', 'RegionID' : 8},
{'Name':'Brandenburg', 'RegionID' : 9},
{'Name':'Saarland', 'RegionID' : 10},
{'Name':'Thüringen', 'RegionID' : 11},
{'Name':'Südbaden', 'RegionID' : 12},
{'Name':'Niederrhein', 'RegionID' : 13},
{'Name':'Hamburg', 'RegionID' : 14},
{'Name':'Schleswig-Holstein', 'RegionID' : 15},
{'Name':'Berlin', 'RegionID' : 16},
{'Name':'Mittelrhein', 'RegionID' : 17},
{'Name':'Rheinland', 'RegionID' : 18},
{'Name':'Baden', 'RegionID' : 19},
{'Name':'Bremen', 'RegionID' : 20}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    newRegion = Region(
    Name=row['Name'],
    RegionID=row['RegionID']
    )

    session.add(newRegion)
    

start = time.time()
session.commit()
print(time.time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the 1.x version:

```py
session.bulk_insert_mappings(Region, data)
session.commit()
```

Or, according to [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#orm-dml-returning-objects) the 1.4/2.0 way of doing it:

```py
from sqlalchemy import insert
# other import statements

[...]  # all your setup code

session.execute(insert(Region), data)
session.commit()
```

Although I must confess that even using these snippets, the SQLAlchemy/BigQuery integration is still really slow, and even using the lower level Core features of `sqlalchemy`, could not achieve better performances.